# Saving function pointer passed by argument

Tags: c

I've following declarations:

```
typedef void (*foo)(int op, int arg1, int arg2);
void goo(foo f);
{
  BODY;
}
```

and I want to store function f passed to goo in my code but the natural way of modifying body and adding global foo variable (I cannot change definition of goo but I'm able to edit body):

```
foo _f;
void goo(foo f);
{
  _f = f;
}
```

is making segfaults. I'd be grateful for any hints.

Comment: I think that assignment should work. Assigning a pointer shouldn't segfault. Your problem is probably with something else.

Comment: Indeed, check if `f` is not NULL (or garbage) when it's given to goo.

Comment: to be honest I think the fault lies in the convention of your code. By convention, with example functions, you use 'foo' and 'bar', not 'goo'. When you don't follow the conventions it tends to make code very hard to read and understand so I think that if you make these adjustments the bug may be easier to see

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tafBQBEa OK you are both partially right, look at link, why does goo calling works perfectely but  page_sim_init makes segfaults?

Comment: @Baranovskiy Does `page_sim_init` generate a segfault even if you use the same arguments for the callback function as the ones you use in `goog`(i.e. `callback(1,1,1)`)?

Comment: Indeed, I'm sure about corectness of callback.

Comment: Does the seg fault happen at the line where the callback is invoked in page_sim_init, are you really sure?  One of your other assignments may be causing the issue.

Comment: Entity of the callback function does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**
Based on your full code, you should change the name of your function callback() in test.c to something other than "callback" as you already defined the symbol in pagesim.c.  I made this edit and the program ran fine.

---

Here is a test that compiles and runs, maybe you can spot your error based on this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void (*foo)(int op, int arg1, int arg2);

foo _f;

void goo(foo f)
{
    _f = f;
    _f(1, 2, 3);
}

void testfxn(int op, int arg1, int arg2) {
    printf("%d %d %d", op, arg1, arg2);
}

void main() {
    goo(testfxn);
}
```

Comment: Look at last comment below main post.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you pasted, where is you actual function definition of type

```
void func(int op, int arg1, int arg2)
```

The segment fault is from `goo()`, you see output from `printf()`, but the following call of `callback2()` generate segment fault. `callback2` is a function pointer, but it doesn't point to any actual function.

you should define a function

```
void func(int op, int arg1, int arg2)
{
     printf("%d %d %d\n", op, arg1, arg2);
}
```

then you call `goo()` and `page_sim_init()` as

```
goo(func);
page_sim_init(page_size, mem_size, addr_space_size,
                    strategy, max_concurrent_operations, func);
```

Comment: I don't know that type are you talking about. At the begining I tried to minimalize example so if you mean typedef void (*foo)(int op, int arg1, int arg2) then it's typedef void (*pagesim_callback)(int op, int arg1, int arg2). Goo executes properly, prints everything what is supposed to. There is segfault at page_sim_init call. Structure of callback2 is as simple as one printf.

Comment: @Baranovskiy from the code you pasted. You directly pass `callback` to  `goo()`, but `callback` is not initialized to point to any actual function yet. It's invalid function pointer. Try to put  `printf("GOO\n");` after line `callback2(1,1,1);`, you will see segment fault first before the message.

Comment: I've marked cutting code at 43. line by '[...]' (look that there are also no includes so far).

Comment: @Baranovskiy Can you post the code that `callback` is initialized? Also, why you are so sure the segment fault is from `callback` in `page_sim_init`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/g8jgrbCa here is whole code, segfault proceeds on callback = _callback assignment.

Comment: you have global variable `callback` as well as function `callback`, when you compile, compiler didn't give you any warning? can you try to change function `callback` to other name and test?